# How to call an action on the actions of redux?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have called the action like this :

```
<Button style={{ margin: 8, borderRadius: 8 }}
          icon="check-circle" mode="outlined" 
          onPress={            
          () => this.props.authenticate(email, password)
          }
          >
```

and the authenticate function like this :

```
import {REQUEST, RECEIVED, FAILED, SIGNOUT, apiUrl} from '../types';
import axios from 'axios'

export function authenticate(email, password) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        console.log('authomy');
      dispatch(startAuthentication())
      return axios({
        url: apiUrl('/api/v1/auth/sign_in'),
        method: 'POST',
        data: { email, password }
      }).then(response => {
        const uid = response.headers['uid']
        const client = response.headers['client']
        const accessToken = response.headers['access-token']
        const expiry = response.headers['expiry']
        dispatch(successAuthentication(uid, client, accessToken, expiry))
      }).catch(error => {
        dispatch(doSignout())
      })
    }
  }

  export function signout() {
    console.log('in signout')
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      const { auth } = getState()
      return axios({
        url: apiUrl('/api/somewhere/sign_out'),
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
          'access-token': auth.accessToken,
          'client': auth.client,
          'uid': auth.uid
        }
      }).then(response => {
        console.log('sent')
        dispatch(doSignout())
        return { type: SIGNOUT }
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        dispatch(doSignout())
        return { type: SIGNOUT }
      })
    }
  }

  export function expireAuthentication() {
    return doSignout()
  }

  export function startAuthentication() {
      console.log('dispatch startAuthentication')
    return { type: REQUEST }
  }

  export function successAuthentication(uid, client, accessToken, expiry) {
    return { type: RECEIVED, uid, client, accessToken, expiry }
  }

  function failAuthentication() {
    return { type: FAILED }
  }

  export function doSignout() {
    return { type: SIGNOUT }
  }
```

I get the error :
Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?

I cant find where the error located exactly

so I added the AuthAction File you demand it, where the error located ???

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVDvV.png)

```
const REQUEST = 'auth/REQUEST'
const RECEIVED = 'auth/RECEIVED'
const FAILED = 'auth/FAILED'
const SIGNOUT = 'auth/SIGNOUT'

export const HOST_URL = 'http://192.168.10.196:3000'
export function hostUrl(route) { return HOST_URL + route }
export const API_URL = 'http://192.168.10.196:3000'
export function apiUrl(route) { return API_URL + route }
export const ASSETS_URL = 'http://192.168.10.196:3000'
export function assetsUrl(route) {
    return ASSETS_URL + route 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the file where you have defined your actions?

Comment: import { startAuthentication, successAuthentication, doSignout, authenticate, logithate } from '../redux/actions/AuthActions';

Comment: Edit your question, reformat it and post the AuthActions file.

Comment: how to add the file ??

Comment: Post the CONTENTS of the AuthActions file, similar to what you already posted.

Comment: done I post the content of the file

Comment: Also, there's no point of using ``return`` in front of the axios call.

Comment: Yes but still the same error undifined "type"

Comment: It's a little hard to determine the error like this. Can you post the error screenshot as well as the types file. Seems like a import mismatch.

Comment: I added the screenshoot of the error !

Comment: the types.js file as well :)

Comment: Added types.js file as well

Comment: Might sound silly, but are you importing the `types.js` file correctly? The error says that the type of action is undefined. That means the action type you are returning is not defined, and that points to a file import issue.

Comment: yes I imprted it correctly

Comment: Everything seems alright here, will need to see the reducer as well as the full component where you are calling the action. Also, have you tried dispatching the action **without** returning the function, for instance like this: ``dispatch({ type: REQUEST })`` directly.  Try replacing this for every dispatch, might work because I faced a similar issue a while back and this approach solved it.

Comment: I wrote an answer, that's probably what the issue is. Get back to me if this does not resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is you are **not** **exporting** the actions from your types.js file.

Try this:

```
export const REQUEST = 'auth/REQUEST'
export const RECEIVED = 'auth/RECEIVED'
export const FAILED = 'auth/FAILED'
export const SIGNOUT = 'auth/SIGNOUT'

export const HOST_URL = 'http://192.168.10.196:3000'
export function hostUrl(route) { return HOST_URL + route }
export const API_URL = 'http://192.168.10.196:3000'
export function apiUrl(route) { return API_URL + route }
export const ASSETS_URL = 'http://192.168.10.196:3000'
export function assetsUrl(route) {
    return ASSETS_URL + route 
}
```